# Reference to an object with disabled copy constructor/assignment

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

In my application I have a list of objects. Since I must have only one instance I've disabled both copy constructor and assignment operator. Moving an object is still allowed. But since I perform various manipulations with the objects I need to store the pointer to one of them. Before I've used pointer for that purpose but I want to use a reference now.

For some reason I cannot reassign reference. The error:

```
error: overload resolution selected deleted operator '='
candidate function has been explicitly deleted
```

The sample code that demonstrates the issue:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Item
{
public:
    Item() { n = (++Item::counter); }
    Item(const Item&& other) { n = std::move(other.n); }
    Item(const Item& other) = delete;
    Item& operator=(const Item& other) = delete;
    int Get() { return n; }
private:
    int n;
    static int counter;
};

int Item::counter = 0;

int main()
{
    Item i1;
    Item i2;

    Item *p = &i1;
    printf("%d\n", p->Get());

    p = &i2;
    printf("%d\n", p->Get());

    Item &r = i1;
    printf("%d\n", r.Get());

    r = i2; // here I get the error
    printf("%d\n", r.Get());

    return 0;
}
```

Ok, I can understand if I get error on something like this:

```cpp
Item i3 = i2;
```

i.e. in case of really assignment. But here I just want to store a reference to the object, not to assign or copy it to another one.

So my question is how can I store a reference to an non-copied object avoiding pointers?

Comment: "For some reason I cannot reassign reference". The reason is that the language doesn't allow it.

Comment: If you were expecting a rebind of that reference to a different object, that's not how the language works. Once bound at required-initialization, a reference can't be unbound (but it *can* be left dangling if you're not careful). In your code, `r = i2;` is *synonymous* to `i1 = i2;`, and you'll find that won't compile either.

Comment: Defining the copy constructor/assignment operator explicitly solves the issue but that is not what I want. As for my that some strange and unexpected side effect when you disable _coping_ and then you cannot store _reference_ to the object and this is definitely not the same thing.

Comment: If you want to change which object is being pointed to you need to stick with pointers, references can only ever point to the object they are first initialised with

Comment: Clearly you can have a reference. You created one. with `Item &r = i1;` But you cannot rebind that reference to a different object like you can with a pointer. That isn't how the language works. And btw, your assessment of `Item i3 = i2;` as *"in case of really assignment"* -  isn't accurate either. That's not assignment, that's [copy-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).

Comment: Ok, thanks guys, it looks that I misunderstood with the C++ references. I'm a little saddened by this uselessness of references. Looks like I'll have to keep working with the pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ references are not rebindable. What does it mean? It means that once reference is created, you cannot change object this reference is refering to. It has major implications - for example this code:

```
Item i1;
Item i2;
Item &r = i1;
r = i2;
```

is logically equivalent to this one:

```
Item i1;
Item i2;
i1 = i2;
```

It should now make sense why compiler has problem with the assignment operator. What is to be done? You can use [std::reference_wrapper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) which is what you want - rebindable reference type:

```
Item i1;
Item i2;
auto r = std::ref(i1);
r = std::ref(i2);
```

Comment: Thanks @bartop, this is a great solution! Unfortunately I didn't know anything about it.